# How to send x509 certificate from client to server WebSocketSharp C#

Tags: c#, websocket, websocket-sharp

I'm trying to send and validate SSL cert beetween client / server with WebSocketSharp

Server side

```
wss = new WebSocketServer(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 6070, true);
string _certificatePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(WSS_Server).Assembly.Location) + "\\cert\\public_privatekey.pfx";
wss.SslConfiguration.ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(_certificatePath, "mypass");
wss.SslConfiguration.ClientCertificateRequired = false; // true;
wss.SslConfiguration.CheckCertificateRevocation = false; // true;
wss.SslConfiguration.ClientCertificateValidationCallback = RemoteCertificateValidationCallback;

wss.AddWebSocketService<MyRemoteService>(
"/myservice",
() => new MyRemoteService()
{
    OriginValidator = val =>
    {
        // Check the value of the Origin header, and return true if valid.
        return true;
    },
    CookiesValidator = (req, res) =>
    {
        return true; // If valid.
    }

});
```

Client side

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:6070/myservice/");
string _certificatePath = "\\cert\\public_privatekey.pfx";
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(_certificatePath, "mypass");
X509CertificateCollection xcol = new X509CertificateCollection();
xcol.Add(x509);

ws.SslConfiguration = new WebSocketSharp.Net.ClientSslConfiguration("127.0.0.1", xcol, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Default, false);
//ws.SslConfiguration.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();
//ws.SslConfiguration.ClientCertificates.Add(x509);

ws.OnOpen += Ws_OnOpen;
ws.OnMessage += Ws_OnMessage;
ws.OnError += Ws_OnError;
ws.OnClose += Ws_OnClose;
ws.Connect();
```

On server side RemoteCertificateValidationCallback *certificate* and *chain* are always **null**

It is like the client never send the cert.

Any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers here worked for me. To make it work I need to set `SslConfiguration.ClientCertificateSelectionCallback` with an appropriate value, like this:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(fileName, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
ws.SslConfiguration.ClientCertificateSelectionCallback =
            (sender,targethost,localCertificates, remoteCertificate,acceptableIssuers) =>
            {
                return cert;
            };
```

In fact, the [documentation of `SslConfiguration.ClientCertificateSelectionCallback`](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/blob/62fba4875b751e4680437bcc2035308e5aee6334/websocket-sharp/Net/ClientSslConfiguration.cs#L158) in WebsocketSharp source code states clearly:

> Gets or sets the callback used to select the certificate to supply to
>   the server. **No certificate is supplied if the callback returns
>   null**. [...] The **default value** is a delegate that invokes **a
>   method that only returns null**.

So, if you do not explicitly provide a client certificate in this callback, no certificate will be sent.

Comment: this was the only solution worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can always set or get the collection that contains client certificates in `WebSocketSharp`.

To accomplish that you can add your `X509Certificate2` object in `ClientCertificates`.

Here you go:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:6070/myservice/");
string _certificatePath = "\\cert\\public_privatekey.pfx";
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(_certificatePath, "mypass");    
ws.SslConfiguration.ClientCertificates.Add(x509);
ws.Connect();
```

Then you can validate this certificate on the server side. Hope this will be the answer to your question.

Comment: if you check my code you see already tried as you said, there are 2 uncomment line, but in that way you will got System.NullReferenceException because ws.SslConfiguration is null. Thas why i did ws.SslConfiguration.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection(); then ws.SslConfiguration.ClientCertificates.Add(x509);

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem i solved it with

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(fileName, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
ws.SslConfiguration.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { };
ws.SslConfiguration.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```